# Send optional field and multipart in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to send image , name and city for the server and all of these can be optional but i don't know how the interface will look like i found a solution with overloading the methods but it makes the code complicated 
The http method is PUT also .

Comment: You can check my answer for this question and get idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249338/how-to-post-image-and-data-in-android-retrofit/56250645#56250645

Answer (score 1):

Use the annotation for Multipart. Create a Map of city and name to be used as PartMap. Pass the image as MultipartBody. Something like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("")
Call<ReturnType> yourCall(@Url String url, @PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> params, @Part MultipartBody.Part multipart, ...);
```

Comment: how can i put the value of params because i want to put string as value

Comment: Make a map of strings and pass it as param

Comment: can you please assist again. that if i have `@Header("token") String token,
            @Query("content") String content,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part image`
how can i make image part as optional

Comment: @MUFAzmi just pass null value for `Multipart.part image ` value. It's done . I m using in that way. Hope this help some one.